I tried connecting MySQL to Azure data studio but I keep getting "XHR failed" as an error message
I get the error message "Error while installing MySQL extension". This is the extension ID "Microsoft.azuredatastudio-mysql"
I was expecting it to just connect directly but it keeps asking me to download a file manually which I did but the issues has not been resolved

You need that mysql driver to make the connection to mysql. I would contact MS customer support for help.


I tried connecting MySQL to Azure data studio but I keep getting "XHR failed" as an error message.

The issue occurs for several reasons, including network connectivity issues, proxy settings, or antivirus software blocking connections.
The some resolutions are:

Go to settings >> Application >> Proxy >> change proxy support to override/on


Go to settings >> Application >> Proxy >> Proxy Authorization >>Edit in settings Json:

in json http.proxyAuthorization it should be null:



Also, you can refer this similar SO thread
